# how to insert data to the salesforce table?

Tags: c#, salesforce

I don't have any idea about Salesforce. i'm using **C#** to connect salesforce. i have a `DataTable` with some columns and values. that columns are **salesforce** `Account` table column. i need to insert the values into the Salesforce `Account` Table.

```
private async Task<ForceClient> ConnectToSalesforceByOAuth(int clientId)
    {
        var property = Properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(SalesforceInstancePropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        var propertyValue = SettingValues.SingleOrDefault(s => s.PropertyName.Equals(property?.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue?.PropertyValue))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to find a valid \"{SalesforceInstancePropertyName}\"");
        }

        var settings = GetOAuthSettings(clientId);
        var authToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SalesforceAuthToken>(propertyValue.PropertyValue);

        // Refresh the auth token in case it has expired
        authToken = await OAuthHelper.ReloadSalesforceAuthentication(clientId, settings, authToken.RefreshToken);

        return new ForceClient(authToken.InstanceUrl, authToken.AccessToken, authToken.ApiVersion);
    }
```

this is the method to connect **salesforce**

```
using (var forceClient = await ConnectToSalesforceByOAuth(clientId))
```

call `ConnectToSalesforceByOAuth` method like the above

```
forceClient.UpdateAsync(string objectname, string recordId, object record);
```

this above line i have to pass the **object** to `record`. but i don't have any class.

i got the filed names using this code.

```
 DataSyncSystem.EissSyncSystemTables.Add(await GetDataSyncSystemTable(forceClient, "Opportunity"));

   var contact = await forceClient.DescribeAsync<SalesforceObject>(Opportunity);
```

and i store the fields to some tables

```
 var table = new DataSyncSystemTable
        {
            TableName = Opportunity,
            EissSyncSystemFields = contact.Fields.Select(f => new DataSyncSystemField
            {
                ColumnName = f.Name,
                Length = f.Length,
                FieldType = f.Type,
                ReadOnly = !f.Updateable
            }).ToList()
        };
        return table;
```

please help me to how to write the query to **salesforce.**
thanks.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_insert_update.htm

Comment: Please add more details, what client are you using to connect? More sample code would also be more helpful? Can you include your full source?

Comment: i try to map `sql` table to `salesforce` table.  i select some **fields** from salesforce. the same fields i have in sql. i want to **insert** the selected filed data to the salesforce table from sql table.

Comment: @thegogz i added more code. can you please help me?

Comment: @Vke unfortunately I don't know much about C# the added code looks good and is very helpful, there's some sample code here https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET for the .net client. You'll need to serialize your data to and from your DB to objects with the properties of the corresponding fields similar to how its done in those examples